# Parsing XML with more sub-elements with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have such XML and I want to parse it into Java object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CreatePreOrderResponse>
    <Errors>
       <Error>
          <Code>code 1</Code>
          <Message>message 1</Message>
          <ErrorElement>element 1</ErrorElement>
       </Error>
       <Error>
          <Code>code 2</Code>
          <Message>message 2</Message>
          <ErrorElement>element 2</ErrorElement>
       </Error>
    </Errors>
</CreatePreOrderResponse>
```

I work with `JAXB` to parse XML string that has no "sub elements", has only one element with its values at the level of `errors`.

**Question:** I would like to know how to get all `Error` elements in `Errors` element, e.g. into List in `CreatePreOrderResponse` object? **Is it possible** to parse it automatically with `JAXB` unmarshaller ro do I have to traverse XML and parse it manually?

---

**NOTE: just for information, this works for me** - these classes I use for parsing this XML (with no sub-elements).

```
<CreatePreOrderResponse>
    <PreOrder>
        <ID>123456789</ID>
    </PreOrder>
</CreatePreOrderResponse>
```

**BtnPreorderResponse**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreatePreOrderResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso(BtnDocLine.class)
public class BtnPreorderResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "PreOrder")
    private BtnPreorder btnPreorder;

    @XmlElement(name = "Errors")
    private BtnErrorListType btnErrorListType;

    public BtnPreorder getBtnPreorder() {
        return btnPreorder;
    }

    public void setBtnPreorder(BtnPreorder btnPreorder) {
        this.btnPreorder = btnPreorder;
    }

    public BtnErrorListType getBtnErrorListType() {
        return btnErrorListType;
    }

    public void setBtnErrorListType(BtnErrorListType btnErrorListType) {
        this.btnErrorListType = btnErrorListType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BtnPreorderResponse{" +
                "btnPreorder=" + btnPreorder +
                ", btnErrorListType=" + btnErrorListType +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**BtnPreorder**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "PreOrder")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BtnPreorder {

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BtnPreorder{" +
                "id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't seem to be including the most important class, BtnErrorListType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you've already implemented individual error clause as class BtnErrorType. Now comes the list of them:

```
@XmlType(name = "Errors")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BtnErrorListType {
    @XmlElement(name = "Error")
    private ArrayList<BtnErrorType> btnError;

    ...
    public ArrayList<BtnErrorType> getBtnError() {
        if (btnError == null)
            btnError = new ArrayList<BtnErrorType>();
        return btnError;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note, that there is only getter and you should call it if you want to add elements to list.